# Emacs daemon not deleting socket

Tags: emacs, sockets

I run Emacs through the

```
emacs --daemon
```

command, which sets up a socket file `/tmp/emacs100/server` for emacsclient to communicate through. When I kill the server as:

```
emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"
```

the socket file remains, preventing me from running `emacs --daemon` again. The same thing happens when I try `M-x kill-emacs` from inside Emacs.
Alternatively, when I try:

```
M-x server-force-delete
```

From within Emacs, I get a message saying:

```
No connection file "/tmp/emacs1000/server
```

Any ideas what is going wrong? How do I start and shut down the emacs server smoothly?

Comment: What version of emacs, on what operating system? Do you have the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -q --daemon`?

Comment: This is version 23.1.1, on Ubuntu 10.04.
I don't have this problem when working with `emacs -q`, I just noticed. I'll need to check my init files again. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I have the same problem. I've traced the problem to a line in server force delete that calls `(delete-file "/tmp/emacs1000/server")`. D'oh. I just realized that I have set `delete-by-moving-to-trash` to true, which means that it is trying and failing to put the server socket file in my trash bin, because it's not a regular file. If this is the same problem as you are having, I will post a solution shortly that will allow you to keep trash mode on but avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i encountered the same problem, apparently

```
(setq delete-by-moving-to-trash nil)
```

fix this...

Comment: Thank you, this works. It makes no sense, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running emacs 23.1.1 and I simply have this line in my .emacs

```
;; Start Emacs server
(server-start)
```

and I have never had a problem with sticky socket files.

And emacsclient works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to disable the trash globally. Just disable it inside each command that might delete the server file. First define a macro as a shortcut for disabling trash inside a function:

```
(defmacro bypass-trash-in-function (fun)
  "Set FUN to always use normal deletion, and never trash.

Specifically, the value of `delete-by-moving-to-trash' will be
set to nil inside FUN, so any deletions that happen inside FUN or
any functions called by it will bypass the trash."
  `(defadvice ,fun (around no-trash activate)
     "Ignore `delete-by-moving-to-trash' inside this function.

See `bypass-trash-in-function' for more information."
     (let (delete-by-moving-to-trash)
       ad-do-it)))
```

Then apply that macro to each of the three server functions that have `delete-file` anywhere in their body:

```
;; Any server function that may delete the server file should never
;; move it to trash instead.
(mapc (lambda (fun) (eval `(bypass-trash-in-function ,fun)))
      '(server-start server-sentinel server-force-delete))
```

Now you can set `delete-by-moving-to-trash` to anything you like.